# Highlight every number that is smaller than all previous numbers in the last column

Tags: linux, text, numeric-data

Input:

```
network-snapshot-000000        time 6m 40s       fid50k_full 34.9546
network-snapshot-000201        time 6m 52s       fid50k_full 30.8073
network-snapshot-000403        time 6m 51s       fid50k_full 33.3470
network-snapshot-000604        time 6m 51s       fid50k_full 32.7172
network-snapshot-000806        time 6m 49s       fid50k_full 30.3764
```

Output:

```
network-snapshot-000000        time 6m 40s       fid50k_full 34.9546
network-snapshot-000201        time 6m 52s       fid50k_full 30.8073*
network-snapshot-000403        time 6m 51s       fid50k_full 33.3470
network-snapshot-000604        time 6m 51s       fid50k_full 32.7172
network-snapshot-000806        time 6m 49s       fid50k_full 30.3764*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 { min = $NF } ($NF < min) { min = $NF; $0 = $0 "*" }; 1' file
network-snapshot-000000        time 6m 40s       fid50k_full 34.9546
network-snapshot-000201        time 6m 52s       fid50k_full 30.8073*
network-snapshot-000403        time 6m 51s       fid50k_full 33.3470
network-snapshot-000604        time 6m 51s       fid50k_full 32.7172
network-snapshot-000806        time 6m 49s       fid50k_full 30.3764*
```

This initializes the smallest found value, `min`, to the first value in the last column if we're currently reading the first line (`NR == 1`).  Then, for each input line, if the value in the last column is strictly smaller than our `min` value, the `min` value is replaced and the current line gets a `*` appended.

Every line is then unconditionally outputted.

Comment: A `NR == 1 { min = $NF; next }` might avoid the strictly smaller test.